# SAS calculate duration of mulitple spells of specific vaules

Tags: loops, sas, duration

I have a dataset that looks like the one below. A person can either be 'passive', 'active' or 'other'. I want to calculate the number of weeks a person is 'passive' before the person becomes 'active'. the variable 'start_week' indicates when the 'passive' spell starts. If a person has more than one 'passive' spell, the observation is reoccurring on the next line, but with a different start_week.

```
ID  y_1449   y_1448   y_1449   y_1450   y_1451   y_1452    y_1501   ...  y_1608  start_week 
01  passive  passive  passive  passive  active   active    active   ...          5
02  other    passive  active   active   active   passive   active   ...          3
02  other    passive  active   active   active   passive   active   ...          7
04
...
N  other   other     other    other    passive   active    active   ...          6
```

The code I have can calculate the duration of the observations with only one spell, but when the observations are reoccurring, something goes wrong and neither of the durations are calculated correctly. I have the following code:

```
%let period = y_1449-y_1452 y_1501-y_1553 y_1601-y_1608;
%let passive = 'passive';
%let active = 'active';

data want;
    data have;
    array y(*) $period;
    transition_to_active=0;
    weeks=0;
    active_week;

    do i=start_week to 62;
         if y(i) in &passive. then do;
              weeks=weeks+1;
         end;

         if y(i) in &active. and y(i+1) in &active. 
         and y(i+2) in &active. and y(i+3) in &active. then do;
             transition_to_active=1;
             active_week=i;
             leave;
         end;
    end;
run;
```

Here 'transition_to active' indicates whether the person have made the tranistion from 'passive' to 'active' and 'active_week' indicates the week that the person makes this transition. 
Can anyone see why the calculation of duration does not work with multiple spells?

Comment: Your data, your description of the algorithm, and your implementation are all somewhat inconsistent. The example records all have start_week set to the (1-based) index of an active week, not a passive week as stated - do you have the description backwards? Why do you require four consecutive active weeks to mark the transition to active? Please show what's actually happening and explain why it's incorrect, rather than just saying 'something goes wrong'.

Answer (score 1):

I think this solves your problem:

```
data input;
input ID start_week y_1447 $  y_1448 $  y_1449 $  y_1450 $  y_1451 $  y_1452  $  y_1501 $;
datalines;
01 3 passive passive passive passive active active  active   
02 5 other   passive active  active  active passive active   
02 7 other   passive active  active  active passive active   
;
run;

%let period = y_1447--y_1501;
%let passive = 'passive';
%let active = 'active';

data want;
set input;
array y[*] &period;
by ID;

last_sw = lag(start_week);
if first.id then
    weeks = start_week-1;
else do;
    start = last_sw;

    weeks = 0;

    do i=start to start_week;
        if y[i]= &passive then
            weeks = weeks + 1;
    end;
end;

drop start last_sw i;
run;
```

Start your counting loop at the last `START_WEEK`, count the number of "passives", and stop when you get to the new `START_WEEK`.

If it is the first time for an `ID`, then you just need the `START_WEEK` minus 1 to get the weeks until start.